# How to add references using BibTex from a .cls file?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am using a bioinformatics template with a user defined bioinfo.cls file.

This is the section where the "Reference" environment is defined.

```
% ***********
% References *
% ***********

\providecommand{\newblock}{}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \section{\bibname}%
  \begingroup
  \small
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\topsep}{\z@}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\z@}%
      \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\z@}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{4mm}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-4mm}}\small}
{\end{list}\endgroup}

\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{cite}
```

And this is how they were initially adding the references.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
        \bibitem[Bofelli {\it et~al}., 2000]{Boffelli03} Bofelli,F., Name2, Name3 (2003) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 199}, 133-154.
        \bibitem[Bag {\it et~al}., 2001]{Bag01} Bag,M., Name2, Name3 (2001) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 99}, 33-54.
        \bibitem[Yoo \textit{et~al}., 2003]{Yoo03}
        Yoo,M.S. \textit{et~al}. (2003) Oxidative stress regulated genes
        in nigral dopaminergic neurnol cell: correlation with the known
        pathology in Parkinson's disease. \textit{Brain Res. Mol. Brain
            Res.}, \textbf{110}(Suppl. 1), 76--84.
        \bibitem[Lehmann, 1986]{Leh86}
        Lehmann,E.L. (1986) Chapter title. \textit{Book Title}. Vol.~1, 2nd edn. Springer-Verlag, New York.
        \bibitem[Crenshaw and Jones, 2003]{Cre03}
        Crenshaw, B.,III, and Jones, W.B.,Jr (2003) The future of clinical
        cancer management: one tumor, one chip. \textit{Bioinformatics},
        doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btn000.
        \bibitem[Auhtor \textit{et~al}. (2000)]{Aut00}
        Auhtor,A.B. \textit{et~al}. (2000) Chapter title. In Smith, A.C.
        (ed.), \textit{Book Title}, 2nd edn. Publisher, Location, Vol. 1, pp.
        ???--???.
        \bibitem[Bardet, 1920]{Bar20}
        Bardet, G. (1920) Sur un syndrome d'obesite infantile avec
        polydactylie et retinite pigmentaire (contribution a l'etude des
        formes cliniques de l'obesite hypophysaire). PhD Thesis, name of
        institution, Paris, France.
    \end{thebibliography}
```

I want to use BibTex instead by using the .bib files. I tried adding it in the file but the references don't show up.

Comment: The initially added refferences, are they in the tex file?

Comment: No i commented them.

Comment: Can you provide the template and a MWE, so we can experiment with it?

Comment: You have been asked yesterday already for the class file. You should not change it.

Comment: *I want to use BibTex instead by using the .bib files.* This sentence contradicts itself. If you want to use BibTeX, you gotta use a database. Have you checked with the journal editors if you are allowed to use BibTeX?